# Multiplayer Games and Wifi / LAN

Tags: wi-fi, firewall, lan

So at work, 2 of my colleagues also have android handsets:

- I have an SGS3 (stock, for now)
- Colleague #1 also has an SGS3 (stock)
- Colleague #2 has an SGS2 (rooted and ROMd)

We have been trying to get some lunchtime android games going, but are not having any luck :(

We have been trying games with local wifi gaming such as Minecraft, Mini Motor Racing, Dungeon Defenders, Guerilla Bob etc. But none of them let us join or even see each others games.

We are all connected to the same wifi. I checked and we had some setting where wifi deices cant see each other, so we switched to an alternate network, still no joy. Also I would of thought there would be some ad-hoc mode available to us if wanting to play in a location without a central AP to connect to.

Using Fing or similar we can see each others devices on the network. Also have tried setting up a wifi direct with the other SGS3 (the SGS2 does not have this feature) but nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be the fact that games use a port that is disallowed on your work network.try using the tethered hotspot on your SGS3 as an alternative.